# Xamarin.Forms GestureRecognizers add shorthand?

Tags: lambda, xamarin, uitapgesturerecognizer, xamarin.forms

Can the following code be simplified any further?

```
var onLogoutTap = new TapGestureRecognizer();
onLogoutTap.Tapped += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
    MessagingCenter.Send(this, "Logout");
};
logoutImage.GestureRecognizers.Add(onLogoutTap);
```

Can the `.Tapped...` portion somehow be passed directly into `TapGestureRecognizer()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The `TapGestureRecognizer` has multiple [constructors](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.TapGestureRecognizer/#Public_Constructors), where you can pass a callback.

```cs
var onLogoutTap = new TapGestureRecognizer(_ => MessagingCenter.Send(this, "Logout"));
```